# Access function parameter in another function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

How to access function's parameter in another function that invoke it, here's what I mean

```
function one(a){
  b();
}

function b(){
  //'a' is the parameter of function one
  if(a>0){
   //do some stuff
  }
}

//the parameter 'a' of function one goes here to catch an event
element.addEventListener('wheel', one);
```

Can I access function one parameter in function b?

Comment: That is like, an absolute basic of JavaScript. See [function definitions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp).

Comment: Do not try it at home `function one(a) { b() }

function b() {
  console.log(arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0])
}`

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is absolute basic of JavaScript !

Comment: Tip: don't think of it in terms of accessing parameters of a higher-up caller. You have no idea where your function will be called from. Make functions self-contained with explicit parameters and return values.

Comment: yes, thanks, returning values is indeed very important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the parameter into b as well

```
function one(a){
  b(a);
}

function b(a){
  //'a' is the parameter of function one
  if(a>0){
   //do some stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, my mistake is was i didn't pass the 'a' parameter in function b declaration. Thanks !

Comment: Yeah we sometimes miss the most basic of things until someone else looks at our code :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `a` to function `b` as follows.

```
function one(a){
  b(a);
}

function b(a){
  //'a' is the parameter of function one
  if(a>0){
   //do some stuff
  }
}

//the parameter 'a' of function one goes here to catch an event
element.addEventListener('wheel', one);
```

Comment: I'd say because this answer duplicates the one given two minutes before. But who knows why someone did this :)

Comment: Because your answer is almost the same with the previous answer posted before you

Comment: An you think it was intended?

Comment: Note that if that was the reason for the downvote, it's wrong/unfair/incorrect/not what we stand for. If an exact duplicate answer was posted *half a year later*, that's spurious. But *2 minutes later* is perfectly within the range of being written simultaneously, and the answer should be judged on its own merit.

Comment: Should I think ManosKounelakis copied @YuryTarabanko 's comment, it was 1min later. You should not copy comments guys.

Comment: My question got downvoted too, maybe because someone thought I didn't try to do it on my own first. I was actually tried it on my own, but failed and I don't know where to ask but here in stackoverflow :)